# Where is best location to store backups that persist after uninstall/reinstall

Tags: android

My app serves folks that generally work in the backcountry for extended periods without any network access.I would like to be able to auto-store backup copies of their data onboard that would persist even if they uninstall/reinstall when able to access the network at some later time. What is the best folder for this?

My app targets Android 11

Comment: The best one is the one that the user selects via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`.

Comment: @CommonsWare (thank you for you reply) I would like to keep it as transparent as possible. Testing Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDocuments) works- kinda. My app can only see media files not my type ".VLD". Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing, outside of some media formats, that you will be able to write from one app installation and read from another... unless you involve the user in the selection via things like `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for taking the time to respond AGAIN! Got it. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Without any user interaction you can write your files to the public Documents directory using File classes or MediaStore.

At reinstall you should use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose that directory.